# Is it possible to replace empty space in form with dots?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, forms

I want to create an empty form which will have several blocks.
After adding text to boxes empty spaces will be replaces with dots.
Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[top=6.5cm,left=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdfpagemode=None,pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{ l@{} r@{} r r}
\Large{МЕНЮ} & & & \\
\hspace{22em} & \hspace{10em} &  \hspace{3em} & \\
  \TextField[bordercolor=white,borderwidth=0,width=3.4in,name=name.1,format={var f =
this.getField('name.1');f.textFont = 'Europe';f.userName = 'first
name'},value=Nazv,charsize=10pt]{} & \TextField[bordercolor=white,borderwidth=0,width=1in,name=qual.1,format={var f =
this.getField('qual.1');f.textFont = 'Europe';f.userName = 'first
name'},value=qual,charsize=10pt]{} & \TextField[bordercolor=white,borderwidth=0,width=0.5in,name=number.1,format={var f =
this.getField('number.1');f.textFont = 'Europe';f.userName = 'first
number'},value=00.00,charsize=10pt]{} & \TextField[bordercolor=white,borderwidth=0,width=0.2in,name=price.1,value=p.]{}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Maybe it's possible to create a new layer, so first layer will be with form and if there will be letters than dots under this layer will be invisible.
Also can I create an item which will add new form same as existing one in document? As far as I can understand Adobe editor can do this. But I don't want to use Adobe ed and my javascript code is buggy.

Comment: Could you add the code you are talking about ? Preferably in the form of a [Minimum Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) ?

Comment: Code example. I want to replace those empty spaces in forms with dots.

Comment: If I understand you, the command \dotfill is all you need.

Comment: No, you don't understand. There is already \dotfill in text. I want to fill form with dots AFTER someone enters info.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how PDF forms work when filled in. This is really outside the scope of TeX and related tools.